# Access to a windows 7 machine from a linux machine on a LAN

Tags: windows

I'm a remote worker at home and the only windows machine is in the living room (Windows 7 64bits).
My office (upstairs) is a small room with an archlinux machine and my employer wants me to use a videoconference software that works only on mac/windows.
Is there a way I could launch this software on the windows machine and get it on my archlinux terminal?
I cannot use the windows machine directly since my kids are usually running with their arms in the air while shouting and crying and it would be difficult to remain professionnal.

Comment: Could you run a virtual machine?

Comment: I tried (with virtualbox) but I've encountered issues with sounds and performances. But I'll probably persist to search for a method to get sounds if there are no other solution.

Comment: My other suggestion would be [nomachine](https://www.nomachine.com/)

Comment: You could try teamviewer, they have a web portal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you is on same LAN you can use easily RDP on Windows. For linux are some tool such as Remmina.

On Windows machine you must do this:

1. Go to Control Panel
2. System and security -> System -> Advanced Setting (on left) - > Remote Access
3. And check Allow connections and next you can set users which can have too remote access to this PC

On linux install Reminna (next info on [Remmina webpage](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/)) and set access by IP/hostname of your Windows PC.

Comment: What would Reminna do regarding any camera and audio (which I assume is needed for video conferencing)

Comment: Fot that exist solution such as from FabulaTech. This is paid, but renew fees are quite cheap. http://www.fabulatech.com/
But you can find some alternatives when someone will be free or cheaper.